# mapreduce ---custom data type

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When i do a mapreduce program,i encounter that the key is a tuple (A,B) (A and B are both integer sets).How can i custom this data type?

```
public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Object,Text,Tuple,Tuple>....

public class Tuple implements WritableComparable<Tuple>{ 


        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this out: http://hadoop-blog.blogspot.in/2012/04/hadoop-example-using-custom-java-class.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to me,but the data type i want to implement is not String pairs.A is Integer set.For example,A={0,1,2,3}.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, just add variables for A and B, and then complete the serialization methods and compareTo:

```
public class Tuple implements WritableComparable<Tuple>{ 
    public Set<Integer> a = new TreeSet<Integer>;
    public Set<Integer> b = new TreeSet<Integer>;

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        a.clear();
        b.clear();

        int count = arg0.readInt();
        while (count-- > 0) {
          a.add(arg0.readInt());
        }

        count = arg0.readInt();
        while (count-- > 0) {
          b.add(arg0.readInt());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        arg0.writeInt(a.size());
        for (int v : a) {
          arg0.writeInt(v);
        }
        arg0.writeInt(b.size());
        for (int v : b) {
          arg0.writeInt(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
        // you'll need to implement how you want to compare the two sets between objects
    }
}
```

Comment: But A and B are not just Integer,they are Integer set.For example,A={0,1,2,3}.

Comment: Just remember to clear the sets between each map iteration - otherwise you'll be accumulating all values seen

Comment: Many thanks.I will try to run it.Your answer give me an inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

to implement a custom datatype in hadoop, you must implement WritableComparable interface and provide the custom implementation for readFields() write() method.
Apart from the implementation of readFiled and write methods must override the equals and hashcode method of java object.

In case of custom data type implementation for the keys must implement comparable interface.